# ChildNodes based on Parent xml Attribute in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

This is my Xml.

```
<SCat>
  <S SId="1" SName="M" FName="MA">
    <Cat>
      <C CId="2" CName="CAS" FName="c-a" />
      <C CId="3" CName="DAC" FName="d-a" />
    </Cat>
  </S>
  <S SId="2" SName="I" FName="IA">
    <Cat>
      <C CId="2" CName="CAS" FName="c-a" />
      <C CId="3" CName="DAC" FName="d-a" />
    </Cat>
  </S>
  <S SId="3" SName="D" FName="DA">
    <Cat>
      <C CId="2" CName="CAS" FName="c-a" />
      <C CId="3" CName="DAC" FName="d-a" />
    </Cat>
  </S>
</SCat>
```

I wrote this code.

```
int Scode = 1;
dsS = new DataSet();
dsS.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path));
```

This is where i am stucked.
I want to get all "Cat" in the Datatable which has attribute "SId" = 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using below XPATH, you will get all the child nodes where `SId ='1'`

```
/SCat/S[@SId='1']/Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use XmlDocument object to load the entire document and then provide the node path and attribute selector. It's all well documented at MSDN ([link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx)). Following is a code snippet from that site:

Listing 1.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample {

  public static void Main() {

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<book xmlns:bk='urn:samples' bk:ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
                "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
                "</book>");

    XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

    //Create a new attribute. 
    string ns = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("bk");
    XmlNode attr = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute, "genre", ns);
    attr.Value = "novel";

    //Add the attribute to the document.
    root.Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr);

    Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML...");
    doc.Save(Console.Out);

  }
}
```

Listing 2 ([link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx))

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
    from el in root.Elements("Address")
    where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == "Billing"
    select el;
foreach (XElement el in address)
    Console.WriteLine(el);
```

Hope this will help. Regards, AB